# Make particular rows of infragistics webdatagrid read only

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I have written an `InitializeRow` event for this, but i am not able to get the cells(e.row.cells) from this to make it read only.

```
protected void grdCrewCTC_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.RowEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)e.Row.Items[1].Value > 5000)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].AllowEditing = Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.AllowEditing.No;          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of doing it at the initializeRow, do it at EnteringEditMode. For example, see: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/37628/218193.aspx